# What post-compiler (or other) options are available for re-using functionality between structs?

Tags: c#, .net, t4, postsharp

Say I've created a `struct`, called `Percent`.  Logically, it makes sense as a struct because it represents a value and should be passed by value whenever used.  The struct also contains a few properties and static implicit operators.  A `Percent` can handle any kind of percentage, including those over 100%.

Now, let's say I'd like to be able to use `Percent` in applications that only care about Percentages between 0-100%.  I decide to create a new struct called `ValidPercent`, which is virtually identical to `Percent` except with additional checks to ensure that a ValidPercent never contains a value above 100% or below 0%.

`ValidPercent` seems like a good candidate for inheritance, but structs cannot take advantage of inheritance.  Additionally, there is very little value in being able to downcast `ValidPercent` to `Percent`.

**Are there any tools available that would allow me to define Percent and ValidPercent without duplicating the majority of the code used within each?**

I've done some cursory research on PostSharp and t4 templates, but I was unable to determine if they could be used for this purpose.  Can they, or are other tools available that can?

Comment: How do you create a valid percent value? Should the ctor of ValidPercent throw on invalid values? In that case you can stick to Percent with an overload to create only "valid" values.

Comment: Yes, the constructor would throw on invalid values.  However, the main benefit here is that the author of a Method can specify a ValidPercent as an argument and offload the validation logic to the struct.  You would get no such benefit from an overloaded constructor.

Comment: You could use Code Contracts for the specific methods to ensure that only Percentage Values with IsValid == true are passed into the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4 can be used for this. Is it the best option? It depends on your scenario (I assume you posted a simplified version of your real scenario).

Anyway, it's possible to define a template which generates a number of variants. Using partial classes and methods you can inject specific behavior into the generated code (such as validation).

You can find the full source code here: https://github.com/mrange/CodeStack/tree/master/q18861246/TestProject

I use VS2013 but this would work fine in VS2008+.

I define a T4 template:

```
<#
    // The model defines *what* we like generated
    var model = new []
    {
        "ValidPercent"      ,
        "Percent"           ,
    };
#>

namespace TestProject
{
<#
    // The "View" defines *how* the model is transformed into code
    foreach (var cls in model)
    {
#>

    partial struct <#=cls#>
    {
        // Partial struct/class are great with T4 or any code-generation tool

        decimal m_value;

        // Partial methods are great to inject customized behavior into the generated code skeleton
        static partial void Partial_ValidateValue (decimal value);

        public <#=cls#> (decimal value)
        {
            Partial_ValidateValue (value);
            m_value = value;
        }

        public decimal Value 
        {
            get
            {
                return m_value;
            }
            set
            {
                Partial_ValidateValue (value);
                m_value = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return Value + "%";
        }

    }
<#
    }
#>

}
```

It's good practice in order to write maintainable meta-programs (my preferred term) to separate the Model *ie what we like to have generated* from the View *ie how the Model is transformed into code*.

In this case the model is very simple:

```
// The model defines *what* we like generated
var model = new []
{
    "ValidPercent"      ,
    "Percent"           ,
};
```

The view basically just iterates over the model generating the code. T4 basically is like ASP/PHP.

```
<#
    // The "View" defines *how* the model is transformed into code
    foreach (var cls in model)
    {
#>
...
```

In order to be able to inject the validation behavior I have inserted into the generated code an extension point:

```
// Partial methods are great to inject customized behavior into the generated code skeleton
static partial void Partial_ValidateValue (decimal value);
```

Partial methods basically works like events but they are hooked up in compile-time. Partial_ValidateValue is called before the assignment of m_value making sure any class invariants are uphold.

In order to inject the validation behavior I define another part of the class ValidPercent in a separate file:

```
partial struct ValidPercent 
{
    public static implicit operator Percent(ValidPercent vp)
    {
        return new Percent (vp.Value);
    }

    static partial void Partial_ValidateValue(decimal value)
    {
        if (value < 0M || value > 100M)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException ("value", "value is expected to be in the range 0..100");
        }
    }
}
```

The operator is just a convenience operator to allow implicit conversion from ValidPercent ==> Percent (this is always safe). Partial_ValidateValue does the actual validation.

This should give you some starting points when thinking about if T4 is right for you.

I hope it helps...

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, especially the suggestion to use partial structs.  The solution I ended up using was a combination of partial classes, and simply reading the original class file as a string and applying necessary changes. For reference, you can use the following to calculate the path to a local file in a T4 template: Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), "YourCodeFile.cs").  Also note that hostspecific must be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that structs dont allow for inheritance you may be looking at migrating to a class. Where you can inherit the class and provide checking of values.

This could be done similar to the following. Just an idea.

```
public class Percent
{

    public static implicit operator double(Percent p)
    {
        return p.Value;
    }


    private Percent() { }

    public Percent(double value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    double value;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            if (!ValidateNewValue(value))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The value '{0}' is not a valid.", value));
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool ValidateNewValue(double value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class ValidPercent : Percent
{

    public ValidPercent(double d)
        : base(d) { }

    protected override bool ValidateNewValue(double value)
    {
        return !(value > 100 || value < 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO it's not obvious that ValidPercent in this regard IS-A Percent. The reason being that I can assign Percent.Value any Value but if for some reason it's a ValidPercent that will throw. This is a bit like the classic OO question: "Square IS-A Rectangle?"